# R: collapse dataframe with similar rows

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Element    Variable
      A       Power
      A     Current
      B       Power
```

I'd like to combine those rows that are equal in `Element` separating the conent of the rows by comas:

```
Element            Variable
      A      Power, Current
      B               Power
```

Comment: `df <- data.frame(Element = c('A', 'A', 'B'), Variable = c('Power', 'Current', 'Power'))`

Answer (score 3):

#### base R

Use `aggregate` and `toString`:

```r
aggregate(Variable ~ Element, df, toString) #toString can be replaced by paste here

  Element       Variable
1       A Power, Current
2       B          Power
```

#### dplyr

Use `group_by` and `toString`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(Element) %>%
  summarise(test = toString(Variable)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

**Data**

```r
df <- data.frame(Element = c('A', 'A', 'B'), Variable = c('Power', 'Current', 'Power'))
```

Comment: Neat @Maël. Superfluously, for those not familiar with `aggregate()`, `Variable ~ .` is equivalent to `Variable ~ Element`.

Comment: Yes, and it actually make more sense here to do it with Element present. edited ;)